# Is IMFSourceReader::GetNativeMediaType equivalent to IMFMediaTypeHandler::GetMediaTypeByIndex?

Tags: windows, ms-media-foundation

Assuming they are from the same source etc is:

```
IMFMediaTypeHandler::GetMediaTypeByIndex(mediaTypeIndex, mediaType)
```

equivalent to:

```
IMFSourceReader::GetNativeMediaType(streamIndex, mediaTypeIndex, mediaType)
```

Is there correspondance between mediaTypeIndex parameters in both cases?  And what does this mean with respect to using MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource() with the following attribute set:

```
attributes->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_DISABLE_CONVERTERS, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods are likely to be equivalent even though they don't have to. If you are using a Source Reader on top of a media source, you delegate the control over media source to reader instance and, generally speaking, you are not supposed to access `IMFMediaTypeHandler` because source reader runs in assumption it has exclusive control over the thing.

It is unlikely that `MF_READWRITE_DISABLE_CONVERTERS` has effect on enumeration on native media types because converters jump in to match requested media type to one of the native media types.

Answer (score 1):

I would says yes :

[IMFMediaTypeHandler::GetMediaTypeByIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-imfmediatypehandler-getmediatypebyindex)

> Retrieves a media type from the object's list of supported media types.

[IMFSourceReader::GetNativeMediaType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsourcereader-getnativemediatype)

> but capture devices might offer several formats.

(I think "list of supported media types" == "might offer several formats", in the example of capture).

And because both implement GetCurrentMediaType. But I must admit that it is not guaranteed.

For MF_READWRITE_DISABLE_CONVERTERS, it will do some conversion when calling SetInput type, if necessary, and if FALSE. So no relationship with GetMediaTypeByIndex/GetNativeMediaType, but only with GetCurrentMediaType, from my point of view.